# Compare node js req.header to a string

Tags: node.js

I try to compare a header to a string in node js and it doesn't work.
Here is my middleware :

I want to compare is csrf equals config.csrf_key.
If i make a console log of csrf and config.csrf_key the result is good.
I try to make : `csrf.toString()` but it change nothing

```
function checkCsrf(req, res, next) {

    var csrf = req.headers['x-csrf-token'];

    if (csrf) {

        if (csrf === config.csrf_key) {
           next();
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(401);
            return res.json({success: false, message: 'Access denied'});
        }

    } else {

        return res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No csrf token provided'
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your variables are strings at the point of comparison? Try logging typeof config.csrf_key == "string" and typeof csrf == "string"

Comment: @Tholle the result of typeof in console.log give me TRUE for both csrf and csrf_key

Comment: That is very odd... Both variables are confirmed to be strings, and output to the log is same for both strings? I don't know what it can be. Hopefully someone else can chime in.